# Fiddler parse duplicate response header keys

Tags: fiddler

The http response from the server contains such headers.

```
Set-Cookie: A=AValue
Set-Cookie: B=BValue
```

When I try to get the values from Fiddler script using following code:

```
oSession.oResponse["Set-Cookie"]
```

I only get the first one, A=AValue.

Do you know how to get the full list of these values even if the keys are duplicated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `headers` property off `oResponse` to get the full collection, then enumerate through each and find them. In C#:

```cs
var headers = oSession.oResponse.headers.Where(h => h.Name == "Set-Cookie").ToList();
```

Here is how you can do it in JScript.NET (Fiddler Script):

```js
var headers = [];
var enumerator = oSession.oResponse.headers.GetEnumerator();
while(enumerator.MoveNext()) {
    var current = enumerator.Current;
    if (current.Name.ToLower() === "set-cookie") {
        headers.push(current.Value);
    }
}
enumerator.Dispose();
```

To explain, this loops over all of the headers, checks the name, and if the name of the header matches, it pushes the value into the `headers` array. After `while` loop, the `headers` array will contain all of the values for the `Set-Cookie` headers.

Comment: Thank you. But I tried, this function is not available in fiddler script.

Comment: @Roger I updated the answer to include how to do it in JScript.NET.